# extract a string with regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm a beginner using regex, I have Strings like `String1= "DELIVERY 'text1' 'text2'"` and `string2="DELIVERY 'text1'"`, I want to extract `"text1"`. I tried this pattern

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^DELIVERY\\s'(.*)'");
 Matcher m2 = p.matcher(string);

                if (m2.find()) {

                    System.out.println(m2.group(1));

                    }
```

the result was :  `text1' 'text2` for the 1st string and  `text1` for the second
i tried this too

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^DELIVERY\\s'(.*)'\\s'(.*)'");
Matcher m2 = p.matcher(string);

                    if (m2.find()) {

                        System.out.println(m2.group(1));

                        }
```

it return a result only for String1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first attempt was almost right. Just replace:

```
.*
```

With:

```
.*?
```

This makes the operator "non-greedy", so it will "swallow up" as little matched text as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex `.*` is "greedy", and consumes as much input as possible yet still match, so it will consume everything from the first to the last quote.

Instead use a *relictant* version by adding `?`, ie `.*?` to costume as little as possible yet still match, which won't skip iver a quote.

Combine this change with some java Kung Fu and you can do it all in one line:

```
String quoted = str.replaceAll(".*DELIVERY\\s'(.*?)'.*", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to have `'text1'`, try this regex:

```
"DELIVERY '([^']*)"
```

or without grouping:

```
"(?<=DELIVERY ')[^']*"
```

Comment: Whilst it works in this example, I wouldn't recommend using a literal space like that. Something like "\s+" is almost always better, as it covers possibilities like multiple spaces or tabs.

Comment: @TomLord you are right. I just copied the string. I think this is not the point to the question. anyway, you are right.